# Elasticsearch C# / .NET Query terms ignored

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

Here is a simplified version of my query:

```
var Match = EC.Search<IndexedData>(_ => _
                .Query(Q => Q.Term(P => P.Category, Category))
                .Query(Q => Q.Term(P => P.Type, Type))
                .Query(Q => Q.Term(P => P.Title, Input) || Q.Term(P => P.Tags, Input))
```

And here are the relevant fields of the class *IndexedData*:

```
[String(Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
public string Tags { get; set; }

[String(Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Analyzer = "English")]
public string Title { get; set; }

public Common.AlbumCategory Category { get; set; }

public Common.MediaType Type { get; set; }
```

*Category* and *Type* are enums.

I have found that whatever I put in my query for *Category* or *Type*, the results from the search are identical. These queries (on enums) are simply ignored.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried Type.GetHashCode() ? and Category.GetHashCode()

Comment: if not try ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Integer)

Comment: You mean to force the enum into an integer before indexing?

Comment: I tried that but I get the same result.

Comment: Did you want to store `enum` as strings or as numeric types in Elasticsearch?